# Pipe and Filter pattern in a Repository pattern returns "does not contain a definition for X... requires a receiver of type IQueryable<Y>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, linqpad, pipes-filters

I'm trying to implement a basic Pipe and Filter pattern and testing it out in LinqPad 5.

The class that contains the extension methods looks as follows:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<PortfolioSection> AreNotDeleted(this IQueryable<PortfolioSection> portfolioSections)
    {
        return portfolioSections.Where(portfolioSection => portfolioSection.IsDeleted == false);
    }
    
    public static int AddMe(this int number, int newNumber){
        return number + newNumber;
    }
}
```

In the Main section of linqpad I do the following:

```
void Main()
{
    PortfolioSections.AreNotDeleted().Dump();
}
```

I've also tried to add AsQueryable to confirm this is not the issue:

```
void Main()
{
    PortfolioSections.AsQueryable().AreNotDeleted().Dump();
}
```

In both cases I get the exception:

> CS1929 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for
> 'AreNotDeleted' and the best extension method overload
> 'MyExtensions.AreNotDeleted(IQueryable)' requires a
> receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I'm following this article to find out more about the Pipe and Filter pattern and originally tried this out in my c# project, but switched to LinqPad when I discovered that the results of my query did not change when I included the extension method AndAreNotDeleted. In my project though there are no exceptions, LinqPad on the other hand throws the exception above.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: As a test try compiling `IQueryable<PortfolioSection> test = null ;  test.AreNotDeleted().Dump(); `. This should compile (but not run). If it does then try compiling `IQueryable<PortfolioSection> test = PortfolioSections ; test.AreNotDeleted().Dump();` to see if this compiles. If it doesn't then there must be some strange with the definition of PortfolioSections. Also can you confirm that your CS1929 error message is **exactly** as you have stated.

Comment: @sgmoore The first compiles as you suggested. The second raises an exception: CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PortfolioSection>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PortfolioSection>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
So it's a DbSet that we're working with and as far as I know DbSet indirectly inherits from IQueryable

Comment: @sgmoore I tried IQueryable<PortfolioSection> test = PortfolioSections as IQueryable<PortfolioSection>; test.AreNotDeleted().Dump(); however test is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection type in Linpad is based on my project's Persistence library containing the DbContext. I had originally copied in all my domain classes representing the data entities forgetting that I simply needed to hit F4 and add a using statement pointing to my library containing the domain classes. This seems to have resolved all my issues in Linqpad and I'm now able to implement the pattern.